# Move (NOT COPY) files & folders on mapped network drive using batch

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, move

I am trying to `move` folder and files from one location to another on the same mapped network drive.

I have used ROBOCOPY and XCOPY. However, they copy and then delete the files. My files can be over 50GB, thus I want to MOVE.

```
move "P:\public\video\recording\123\*.*" "P:\public\video\recording\"
move /S "P:\public\video\recording\123\*.*" "P:\public\video\recording\"
move "P:\public\video\recording\123\*" "P:\public\video\recording\"
move "P:\public\video\recording\123\*" "P:\public\video\recording."
```

**None of the above work**.

I am not sure if it is possible?

I have tried so many different variations with no success.

Additional information

Okay, reading the comments, this command working on a network share?

I have noticed the follow:

1. When moving only files, the script moves them, not copies them. Tested with a 40GB file.
2. When you have folders with files, it copies and then deletes them after.

These are my observations thus far.

Comment: Why do you expect your commands to work when the directories are the same?

Comment: @DavidPostill I assume there are subdirectores inside the folder that OP wants to move to a higher level, but for the technicality of the question does not really matter if the paths are incorrect. What matters is that this will not work ever on mapped network shares. It will only move locally, because the File Allocation Table needs to be altered, which can only be done on local drives.

Comment: I have updated it. Right, so this cannot be done on a mapped network drive. Please can you have a look at the additional information please.

Comment: Please do not edit the question and create a new question invalidating earlier answers. Ask a new question instead. The answer to the addition is completely different from the earlier part. I do know the answer, but it becomes really impractical and hard to read.

Comment: @LPChip Well, it is the same question, except for the fact that files are moved whereas if you have folders and files, the are not moved. They are copied and deleted after. Theses are my observations.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I can move files and folders on a mapped network drive without any issues. They are not copied except when multiple file systems are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is what makes it not working.

Because you go from network to network location, a copy is always used, also when performed from explorer.

This is because your computer does not know that it is on the same harddisk.

In order to move the files and only alter the table of content, you need to perform the action on the computer/server where the files are actually hosted, so the command knows it only needs to alter the index of the harddrive rather than physically copy/delete the files.

You can do it with the move command, you just have to do it on the physical drive itself. If you are on the physical compouter, but you still use a network share, even if that network share links to the same computer, it will not work. So if your P:\public links to c:\shares\public, you have to perform the move command on c:\shares\public, not p:\public.

Comment: File operations on the same share do of course support renaming (and as such, moving). The SMB server can respond with `NT_STATUS_NOT_SAME_DEVICE` if it’s really not possible. Windows even abstracts this away so you don’t have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the technicalities of your question, it should work as you state, unless those commands implement some kind of security feature. Why? things can fail and you loose your files. BTW You can do such tasks using Windows Explorer via Cut and Paste, but if something goes wrong you loose your files. I understand (or assume at least) you want a direct answer to the question and not exactly asking for advice, but based on years of facing issues on networks, I would never approach such task moving files directly, I would copy first, then delete. Why? years of stuff I've seen and experience.

Other than that, cut and past via Windows Explorers works on drives and USB memories. I wouldn't advice doing it that way but kinda fits the question.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is not true. You cannot move files that resides on a network share. It will always copy then delete the files. Moving files will alter the File Allocation Table and simply change the path to the file rather than changing the bits on the harddisk. This makes it so you can move 50 GB of files in an instant. This is what OP wants.

Comment: Can the same be said for ONLY files, not folder? I moved a 40GB file with no use on the same mapped network drive?

Comment: Don't know if this would fit your needs, just tried it on my network, it worked.

As said before, Windows Explorer Cut & Paste
It proceeds to copy and then delete, yes, but file-by-file
It won't copy everything and then delete, it will do so one by one.

That's what I meant, sorry if I wasn't detailed enough. *But* if you mean moving files like you do on a local disk, something that will happen in the blink of an eye, that's not possible on networks or different drives.